# JSOUP duplicate html table

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to filter html tables with the library `JSOUP`.
It filter perfectly but it create some duplicates of tables.

this is my syntax:

- `doc1` is a `Document`
- `content` is a `String` with the html document.
- `tabelletotali` is an array of document

---

```
doc1 = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(content);
tabelletotali = doc1.getElementsByTag("table");
```

---

in `tabelletotali` goes all tables but with redundancy.

What wrong?

Comment: Show us the value of content

Comment: Do you have nested tables?

Comment: Sorry i cant' t show you the value of content, there are company information. But I can tell you that there are tables nested . I think that is the problem, how i can solve it? I cant and i do not want modify the html code manually

Answer (score 1):

The method you are currently using - `getElementsByTag()` - recursively finds and selects ALL elements with the specified tag name. If you need to select only the parent-level tables and not the nested tables as well, use the `select()` method with the `>` selector:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Elements e = doc.select("body > table");
```

This selects only child elements that directly descend from the parent element (e.g. body in this example) which means that the nested tables won't be selected twice.

Comment: thank you very much, I did not know that syntax, I tried it and it works. thanks again

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you!